# Вызов runnable в таймере

Tags: java, android, android-threads

Есть ли проблема в этом коде:

Внутри активити, каждые 10 секунд в таймере вызывается следующий код

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        textView.setText(getText());
    }
});
```

анонимный Runnable каждый раз будет выполняться и удаляться из памяти? или пока не остановишь таймер будет забивать память новым экземпляром? И что будет после выхода из этого активити? кроме NPE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отработавшие экземпляры будет прибирать GC, но не моментально, что при высокой частоте создания анонимов или загрузке процессора может привести к OOM.
К тому же будут расходоваться часть ресурсов на создание и очистку этих объектов.
Если выйти из активности, не остановив таймер, то он, как и любой поток будет удерживать в памяти всё, на что ссылается и продолжать плодить анонимы.

P.S. В вашем примере можно использовать один экземпляр, созданный до старта таймера.

Comment: Получается необходимо внутри активити создать экземпляр runnbale? он должен быть static? p.s. уведел тут информацию об этом https://bit.ly/2XTcijI

Comment: Там немножко о другом. Ссылка на экземпляр `Runnable` не должна быть статической, иначе она сама будет держать его в памяти после закрытия активности.

Comment: В этом материале как раз делают ссылку static, если не трудно что там хотят донести? Я не совсем понял значит тот материал...

Comment: Да, в общем там всё верно - аноним, созданный не в статическом контексте неявно ссылается на объект, в котором создан. Но в таком случае вам придётся явно передать ему эту ссылку, чтобы получить доступ к `textView` и `getText()`. И это станет источником той же утечки, поэтому её нужно будет завернуть в `WeakReference`. У них по условию задача будет торчать в очереди 10 мин. и всё это время GC не сможет прибраться. А если вы можете остановить поток таймера сразу при закрытии активности и тем самым освободить ссылки, то можно так не извращаться.

Comment: Получается что даже мой код который выше нормально будет работать если при закрытии формы отменять таймер?
И любой другой анонимный runnable будет нормально работать если  он не вызывается с задержкой?

Comment: Почитайте лучше, что такое утечка памяти (в принципе и в контексте Андроида), как и почему она происходит. Из двух примеров кода вы всё-равно не поймёте что к чему и как этого избежать в дальнейшем.